# Unexpected state behaviour while dynamically rendering elements in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-tsx

I have those elements inside an array rendering dynamically in a `.map()`.

I try passing them in a Form Component which is rendered inside a modal and for some reason the state I pass into the form component gets messed up.

```
<Row>
      {fens?.map(
        (
          fen: {
            _id: string;
            fen: string;
            description: string;
            san: string;
          },
          index: number
        ) => (
          <Col>
            <Card title={fen.fen}>
             [..stuff..]
                {isLogged && (
                  <>
                    <p>
                      <strong>Description:</strong>
                      {fen.description}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <strong>Correct move:</strong>
                      {fen.san}
                    </p>
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => {
                        setIndex(index);
                        //setFen(fen.fen);
                        //setSan(fen.san);
                        setIsEditPositionModalVisible(true);
                      }}
                    >
                      <strong>Edit Position</strong> <EditOutlined />
                    </Button>
                    <Modal
                      title="Edit Position"
                      visible={isEditPositionModalVisible}
                      onOk={() => setIsEditPositionModalVisible(false)}
                      onCancel={() => setIsEditPositionModalVisible(false)}
                    >
                      {/* formcomponent */}

                      <FormComponent
                        description={fen.description}
                        index={_index}
                        fen={fen.fen}
                        san={fen.san}
                        setFens={setFens}
                        password={pass}
                        id={fenId as string}
                        type={"edit"}
                        setIsModalVisible={setIsEditPositionModalVisible}
                      />
                    </Modal>
                  </>
                )}
              </p>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        )
      )}
    </Row>
```

And the code inside the FormComponent:

```
return (

  [...]
    <Form.Item
      name="fen"
      label="Fen"
      tooltip="add a valid position in Forsyth-Edwards Notation"
      initialValue={props.fen}
  
    </Form.Item>
  [...]
```

);

the highlight of the code is when I pass data inside the FormComponent, and use it to set the initialValue. All the fields inside the Form component are initialized to what it seems to be the last element of the array. I tried setting up the field on the onClick based on the index and at first they are initialized correctly but then when I try closing the modal and opening another one the values remain unchanged..

I'm using antd for styling but I don't think that's relevant.

**Edit**: I've just noticed a strange behaviour that kinda make sense: by using just a state variable (i.e. `isEditPositionModalVisible`) I'm probably opening all the modals at once and the last to render is logically the last one on the array. Maybe that's the right track but I can't figure out a way of managing dynamically rendered modals honestly.

**Edit2**: I think I've found the problem but not the solution. I pass the initial values inside the  as props and since I'm using only a single instance of a modal the rendered values don't change. I don't know if that's a antd problem but apparently initialValues inside <Form.Items /> are not synced. Hope someone knows how to dynamically change them.

**Edit3**: Okay maybe I found a solution but by googling I can't find anything helpful: is there a way to artificially unmount a functional component? The idea is basically destroying the component when the modal is not showing and mounting it when it shows. It might solve all the problems.

**Edit4** as requested here there is a sandbox for my code:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-forked-j9p17h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

the important part is at the end, when I map through the fens. You can notice immediately that when opening a modal with the "Edit Position" button for a second time the InitialValues of the form inside that particular modal don't change.

Comment: consider using a key prop inside your map function https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#picking-a-key

Comment: I did but that doesn't solve the problem. I tried using an array to manage all the modals and moving the modal out of the .map() function but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Pogus Can you please create a sandbox for your code?

Comment: @NoumanRafique https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-forked-j9p17h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using Antd Form. You can use antd form hook to set, reset & get values. You don't need to pass each property to `FormComponent`.

1. First create an antd hook like this:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```

2. When you click on Edit Position button, you already have `fen` record for that particular card, just set form values using `form.setFieldsValues({...})` like this:

```
<Button
    onClick={() => {
        form.setFieldsValue(fen);
        setIndex(index);
        setIsEditPositionModalVisible(true);
    }}
>
    <strong>Edit Position</strong> <EditOutlined />
</Button>
```

3. Pass `form` prop to FormComponent.
4. Add `form: FormInstance;` in your `PropsInterface`
5. Pass form Prop To antd Form

```
<Form form={form}> </Form>
```

6. You don't need to use initialValue in `Form.Item`. Since you already set values using form.setFieldsValue().
7. When you click on `Add Position`, just reset the form using `form.resetFields()`.

Hope this solve your problem.

Please follow the antd [Form API](https://ant.design/components/form/).

Comment: it worked like a charm, thanks! Though I have one more problem: syncing the fen field with the board showing inside the modal. Validation is fine since I am using the `form?.getFieldValue("fen")` method in an useEffect inside FormComponent so as soon as the user modifies the form everything start working, the problem is that the board doesn't renders correctly at the beginning. Obviously passing the fen as a prop doesn't get me anywhere so I have no idea how to solve this one. Have you any suggestion? I have to mention that by using `getFieldValue` inside Chessground the board renders...

Comment: ...correctly but I honestly wanted to keep the fen inside a the PropComponent state so I could do all the validations more easily.

Comment: i didn't understand the exact issue you are facing. We can have a discussion in chatroom and get it fixed. Please create a chatroom and let me know

Comment: sure! How do I join a chatroom with you? That's my first time..

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244133/antd-dynamic-content-rendering-issue

Comment: Just send you a request on discord.